# Display Alerts VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that has the in the top line (after dimming my variables) the two lines

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

my issue is that despite having these during my macro I still get a pop-up asking me if I want to update links or not.  Does anyone know why this may be happening / a way to fix it?

Thank you very much (I didn´t include my code because the reason the update links thing pop up is due to the documents I'm opening and not the code itself)

Comment: Additionally when I step through the code Display alerts remains true even after reading the display alerts = false line...It's not commented so I don´t see why it is doing this?

Comment: Setting `DisplayAlerts` to False only applies during the current code (Macro) execution. From the Help: "If you set this property to False, Microsoft Excel sets this property to True when the code is finished, unless you are running cross-process code."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to apply this at the vba level any time during the execution of the code you can either apply the restriction at workbook level or at application level like so

```
WorkbookName.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
AppExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
```

Answer (score 4):

When you open workbooks, be sure to include UpdateLinks = false in the parameters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

> Specifies the way external references (links) in the file, such as the
>   reference to a range in the Budget.xls workbook in the following
>   formula =SUM([Budget.xls]Annual!C10:C25), are updated. **If this
>   argument is omitted, the user is prompted to specify how links will be
>   updated.**

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 3):

Second parameter of `Workbooks.Open method` allows you to avoid pop-up asking for links update. Try to use the following syntax to update external links:

```
Workbooks.Open path_file, TRUE, ...
```

of set it to `FALSE` to not update.

For additional information [visit this MSDN link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194819%28v=office.14%29.aspx)